# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am getting the Error, I am writing a function to monitor a path for. I am new to Node.js:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>
> at C:\Users\a\Desktop\DL\file\filemonitor.js:15:14
> at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:149:20)

```js
const Promise = require ('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

monitordir(monitorpath) {
  var fileList = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(monitorpath,function(err, items) {
      items.map((file) => {
        fileList.push(file);
      });
      resolve(fileList);
    });
  })
}
```

**Note: I don't see a `package.json` file either. Should I have a sucessful run to see it**

Comment: So, what would ypu suggest i need to do to rectify it. I was told that Promise.promisifyAll you add a suffix Aysnc and hence i added a function to readdir

Answer (score 1):

When you run `var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));` it return a promise to you. So you can't execute a map of a promise.

I believe that you don't need a Promise to resolve `fs` module, my suggestion is you write something like that.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = require("fs");

const monitordir = path => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(path, (error, items) => {
            if (error) return reject(error)
            return resolve(items);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: So i change my code to this and i still get the same error  const Promise = require('bluebird');
//var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
var fs = require('fs');    monitorDir(monitorPath) {
        var fileList = [];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.readdir(monitorPath, function(err, items) {
            items.map((file) =>{
              fileList.push(file);
            });
            resolve(fileList);
          });      
        })
      }

Comment: Hey buddy! I created a gist to show you how I implemented the code above.

https://gist.github.com/nicolastakashi/7cb5cbea674a586f644ee561e96d3ac6 

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try following fix, see if it fits your needs:

```
monitordir(monitorpath)
{
    var fileList = [];
    return fs.readdir(monitorpath)
        .then(function(err,items) {
            items.map((file) => {
                fileList.push(file); // fileList is ready here! do whatever you want before it resolves to caller
            });
            return fileList;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            // something bad happened; throw error or handle it as per your needs
            throw new Error(e);
        });
}
```

For `package.json` you can run `npm init` command at your project directory it will create one for you.

Comment: Found out the answer, the monitor path was not setup right

Comment: great, but still I would suggest you to try to drop additional `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {` since you have `promisified` the `fs` module, it will look cleaner and better without extra code needed.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan, will do that